# Spresnse でデータ受信速度の遅延が発生する

Tags: spresense

Spresenseを使って、セットしたmicroSD上に音声のFFT結果をcsvファイルの形式でデータ収集させているのですが、そのデータ受信速度が日に日に長くなっています。何か原因として考えられることはございますか。

なお、ボードはArduino IDEで動かしており、使用しているスケッチは、書籍「SpresenseではじめるローパワーエッジAI」159ページに載っている、Chapter8の「fft_datacollection.ino」と全く同じ内容です。
はじめは約1秒間隔でとれていたものが、現在約6秒間隔となっています。（ハードウェア、スケッチ双方とも変えた心当たりがありません）

```c
#include <Audio.h>
#include <FFT.h>
#include <SDHCI.h>
SDClass SD;

#define FFT_LEN 1024

// モノラル、1024サンプルでFFTを初期化

FFTClass<AS_CHANNEL_MONO, FFT_LEN> FFT;

AudioClass* theAudio = AudioClass::getInstance();


void avgFilter(float dst[FFT_LEN]) {
  static const int avg_filter_num = 8;
  static float pAvg[avg_filter_num][FFT_LEN/2];
  static int g_counter = 0;
  if (g_counter == avg_filter_num) g_counter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < FFT_LEN/2; ++i) {
    pAvg[g_counter][i] = dst[i];
    float sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < avg_filter_num; ++j) {
      sum += pAvg[j][i];
    }
    dst[i] = sum / avg_filter_num;
  }
  ++g_counter;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  // SDカードの挿入を待つ
  while (!SD.begin()) {Serial.println("Insert SD card");};

  // ハミング窓、モノラル、オーバーラップ50%
  FFT.begin(WindowHamming, AS_CHANNEL_MONO, (FFT_LEN/2));

  Serial.println("Init Audio Recorder");
  theAudio->begin();
  // 入力をマイクに設定
  theAudio->setRecorderMode(AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_MIC);
  // 録音設定：フォーマットはPCM (16ビットRAWデータ)、
  // DSPコーデックの場所の指定 (SDカード上のBINディレクトリ)、
  // サンプリグレート 48000Hz、モノラル入力
  int err = theAudio->initRecorder(AS_CODECTYPE_PCM 
    ,"/mnt/sd0/BIN", AS_SAMPLINGRATE_48000, AS_CHANNEL_MONO);                             
  if (err != AUDIOLIB_ECODE_OK) {
    Serial.println("Recorder initialize error");
    while(1);
  }

  Serial.println("Start Recorder");
  theAudio->startRecorder(); // 録音開始
}


void loop() {
  static const uint32_t buffering_time = 
      FFT_LEN*1000/AS_SAMPLINGRATE_48000;
  static const uint32_t buffer_size = FFT_LEN*sizeof(int16_t);
  static const int ch_index = AS_CHANNEL_MONO-1;
  static char buff[buffer_size];
  static float pDst[FFT_LEN];
  uint32_t read_size;

  // buffer_sizeで要求されたデータをbuffに格納する
  // 読み込みできたデータ量は read_size に設定される
  int ret = theAudio->readFrames(buff, buffer_size, &read_size);
  if (ret != AUDIOLIB_ECODE_OK && 
      ret != AUDIOLIB_ECODE_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER_AREA) {
    Serial.println("Error err = "+String(ret));
    theAudio->stopRecorder();
    while(1);
  }

  if (read_size < buffer_size) {
    delay(buffering_time);
    return;
  }
  
  FFT.put((q15_t*)buff, FFT_LEN);  //FFTを実行
  FFT.get(pDst, 0);  // FFT演算結果を取得
  avgFilter(pDst); // 過去のFFT演算結果で平滑化

  static uint32_t last_capture_time = 0;
  uint32_t capture_interval = millis() - last_capture_time;
  // 1秒経過したら記録する
  if (capture_interval > 1000) {
    theAudio->stopRecorder(); // 録音停止
    // saveData関数：SDカードにデータを記録  
    //   データへのポインタ（pDst）
    //   記録データのサイズ（FFT_LEN/8）
    //   データ保存数（100）
    saveData(pDst, FFT_LEN/8, 100); 
    theAudio->startRecorder(); // 録音再開
    last_capture_time = millis();
  } 
}

// SDカードにデータを記録
void saveData(float* pDst, int dsize, int quantity) {
  static int gCounter = 0;  // ファイル名につける追番
  char filename[16] = {};

  // 指定された保存数以上に達したら何もせずにリターン
  if (gCounter > quantity) {
    Serial.println("Data accumulated");
    return;
  }

  // データ保存用ファイルを開く
  sprintf(filename, "data%03d.csv", gCounter++);
  // すでにファイルがあったら削除する
  if (SD.exists(filename)) SD.remove(filename);
  // ファイルをオープン
  File myFile = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
  // データの書き込み
  for (int i = 0; i < dsize; ++i) {
    myFile.println(String(pDst[i],6));
  }
  myFile.close();  // ファイルをクローズ
  Serial.println("Data saved as " + String(filename));
}
```

Comment: 単純に SDcard のアクセス時間が伸びただけかも。新品カード（産業用クラスの高耐久品）に変えたらどうなるか試してみてほしいっス。激安 SDcard はこの手の長期間ずっと書き込み続ける目的には全く向かないです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。一度も試したことが無かったので、試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

組み込み向けに実装されているFATファイルシステムは、ファイル数が多くなるとアクセス速度が遅くなります。そのためではないでしょうか？この場合、ファイルを複数のフォルダに分割することで改善することができます。

英語版のスタックオーバーフローのやりとりを貼り付けておきます。ご参考になれば。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821728/fatfs-significant-slow-down-in-directories-with-many-files